# How to use percentages with Jquery code for Hover Fade

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, image-size

So, I'm quite new to web design and I've been searching for ways to go about creating a website that uses percentages (specifically, 33.333% or thirds) in order to divide the website into thirds, and inside of each of those divisions there is an image that will fade to another image on hover.

I've spent some time finding jquery code that will fade, but I'm stuck on how to translate the code into a website using percentages.  At the moment, the images are stuck at a specific size, otherwise they begin to overlap.  Basically, I want the images to each take up a third of the page with auto height.

HTML;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="images">

    <div id="1r1">
        <img src="images/TestImage1.jpg" alt="Asteroids" class="on">
        <img src="images/TestImageOff.jpg" alt="AsteroidsOff" class="off">
    </div>

    <div id="2r1">
        <img src="images/TestImage2.jpg" alt="Asteroids" class="on">
        <img src="images/TestImageOff.jpg" alt="AsteroidsOff" class="off">
    </div>

    <div id="3r1">
        <img src="images/TestImage3.jpg" alt="Asteroids" class="on">
        <img src="images/TestImageOff.jpg" alt="AsteroidsOff" class="off">
    </div>

</div>



<script src="js/lib/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS;

```
body {
margin: 0;
}

.images div {
float: left;
display: inline;
position: relative;
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
}

.images div img.off {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}

.images div img.on {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 99;
}
```

Jquery;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // when hover over any div inside div with class=photos, find
   // the grey image and change its opacity to 0
   // opacity = 0 - invisible, opacity = 1 - completely opaque
$('.images div').hover(
  function() {
      $(this)
      .find('img.on')
      .stop()
      .animate({ 'opacity': '0' }, 800);
  },
  function() {
      $(this)
      .find('img.on')
      .stop()
      .animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 800);
  });

});
```

I feel as though there is a simple solution to this, I'm just very unsure about using the CSS elements to achieve what I would like. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use percentages directly into CSS. It will not be a third exactly, but should do the job:

```
.images div {
float: left;
display: inline;
position: relative;
height: 500px;
width: 33%;
}
```